# How to get a value from a webpage using java

Tags: java, html, css

In the follwing URL **http://www.manta.com/c/mx4s4sw/bowflex-academy** I want to get the **SIC Code**. Here is my code and error :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
        Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.manta.com/c/mx4s4sw/bowflex-academy").ignoreHttpErrors(true).get();
        String textContents = doc.select("itemprop").first().text();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

`Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.inndata.connection.GoogleScraperDemo.main(GoogleScraperDemo.java:22)`

Comment: Access to the website is blocked?

Comment: i can access the URL from my browser.

Comment: Why do you think `doc.select("itemprop")` will return anything?

Comment: i want the SIC code from the <tr>  tag i am trying to get the value : <tr>
                      <th class="text-left" style="width:30%;">SIC Code</th>
                      <td rel="sicDetails"><span itemprop="isicV4">7991</span>, Physical Fitness Facilities</td>
                  </tr>

Answer (score 0):

The selector `"itemprop"` is incorrect.

The SIC code in the document is in a block of HTML that looks like this:

```
  <tr>
      <th class="text-left" style="width:30%;">SIC Code</th>
      <td rel="sicDetails"><span itemprop="isicV4">7991</span>, Physical Fitness Facilities</td>
  </tr>
```

The selector should be something like

```
"span[itemprop='isicV4']"
```

I have not tested this. Also, this will break whenever the website owners change the layout or `itemprop` value on that line.  You could get fancier looking for the string `SIC Code` and then searching just below, but any such scraping is likely to be brittle to website changes, and there's not much you can do except react after the fact.

Comment: i tried like this , 
 try {
  Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.manta.com/c/mx4s4sw/bowflex-academy").ignoreHttpErrors(true).get();
  Elements spans = doc.select("span[itemprop='isicV4']");
  System.out.println(spans.isEmpty());
 } catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
 }
  }
Getting true when i am printing the value

Answer (score 0):

The website, you are trying to scrape doesn't allow scraping. If you use third party tools like Jsoup, HtmlUnit then it will detect it as bot.

So try using in-built library "java.net" of java to fetch webpage and you are good to scrape.

Here are some key steps to proceed -

1. create URL Object from url String -

   `URL url = new URL(targetPageURLString);`
2. Open http connection through URL -

   `HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();`
3. Read web response from input stream -

   `InputStream urlStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();`
4. After reading response from stream byte by byte, convert this byte array to String.
5. Using regex, you can get required info/content